# Is it possible to skip a paragraph using arrow::open_dataset in r?

Tags: r, tidyverse, apache-arrow

I have 20 datasets, and some of them have introductions in the first few rows. Since not all the dataset have introduction and the number of rows of introductions from different datasets may not be the same, therefore `skip_rows` may not be useful. Is it possible to catch the keywords and start reading from the row that contains keywords?

Sample dataset:

dataset 1:

| balabala | balabala... |
| --- | --- |
| A header | Another header |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

dataset 2:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

dataset 3:

|balabala  | balabala...    |
|balabala  | balabala...    |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A header | Another header |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |

etc...

What I want:

dataset 1:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

dataset 2:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

dataset 3:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df1 <- read.table(text = "balabala  balabala...
'A header'  'Another header'
First   row
Second  row", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "'A header'    'Another header'
First   row
Second  row", header = T, check.names = F)

df3 <- read.table(text = "balabala  balabala...
balabala    balabala...
'A header'  'Another header'
First   row 
Second  row", header = T)

header_vector <- c('A header', 'Another header')

ftn <- function(df){
  if (all(names(df) == header_vector)) {
    df
  } else {
    df$key = apply(df, 1, function(x) {all(x == header_vector)})
    df %>%
      mutate(key = cumsum(key)) %>%
      filter(key >= 1) %>% select(-key) %>%
      janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) 
  }
  
}

ftn(df1)
  A header Another header
2    First            row
3   Second            row


ftn(df2)
  A header Another header
1    First            row
2   Second            row

ftn(df3)
  A header Another header
2    First            row
3   Second            row
```

Comment: Since I have more than 100 datasets, therefore I may be able to open one by one by hand. Also, the size of each dataset is very large(>2gb), so read.table is not suitable for opening such large dataset...

Comment: @doraemon `read.table` is just to put your data to my workspace. Make your dataset as list and try `lapply(your_list, ftn)`